# Find the symmetrical point of $(1,2,3)$ and orthogonal to the plane $x+y+z=3$.

Tags: geometry, symmetry

Find the symmetrical point of $(1,2,3)$ and orthogonal to the plane $x+y+z=3$.

---

I know that $\vec{n} = {1,1,1}$ is a normal vector for the plane $x+y+z = 3$. Then the vector form of the line going through $(1,2,3)$ would be $\vec{r} = (1, 2, 3) + t(1,1,1)$. Two point is symmetric if their distance from the origin is the same, so we must have that $d = \sqrt{1 +4 + 9} = \sqrt{14} = \sqrt{(1-t)^2 + (2+t)
^2 + (3 + t)^2}$.

$\implies 3t^2 + 8t = 0$

$\implies t = \frac{-8 \pm \sqrt{64}}{6} \implies t = -\frac{8}{3}$

So the point that is symmetric to $(1,2,3)$ and orthogonal to the plane $x+y+x=3$ is $(\frac{-5}{3}, \frac{-1}{3}, \frac{1}{3})$

---

Is the above solution I have given correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sqrt {1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2}$ is the distance your point is from the origin not from the plane

The distance of a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ a plane $ax + by + cz - d = 0$

$\frac {|ax + by + cz - d|}{\sqrt {a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}$

or
$d = \frac {(p_1-p_0)\cdot n}{\|n\|}$ where $p_1$ is a point on the plane, and $p_0$ is your point.

and in the specific case $\frac 3{\sqrt 3}$

The reflection of your point.  Travel twice the distance along the normal line.

$(1,2,3) - 2 \frac {3}{\sqrt 3}\frac {n}{\|n\|} = (1,2,3) - 2(1,1,1) = -1,0,1$

Comment: Why is it twice the distance?

Comment: if you travel the 1x the distance you are on the plane,  and you travel 1x the distance again and you are an equal distance on the opposite side.

Answer (score 0):

$1+2+3=6$. You are looking for the point which $x+y+z=0$ so that the plane $x+y+z=3$ be right between.

$\vec{r} = (1, 2, 3) + t(1,1,1)$, $$1+t+2+t+3+t=0$$
$$t=-2$$
So the point is $(-1,0,1)$